# Few basic jQuery concepts (splitting code into files, settings storage, modular systems)

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, web-frontend

Right now I'm writing a small jQuery plugin for fun and profit, so since I'm not too familiar with this library, there's a few questions made me confused at this point.

Let's say we have a pretty simple plugin:

```js
(function($) {

  onButtonPress() {
    console.log('Button pressed!'); 
  }

  render(container, settings) {
    $(container).addClass(settings.boxClass);
    $('<button></button>').appendTo(container).addClass(settings.addImageButton).on('click', onButtonPress); 
  }

  $.fn.myAwesomeForm = function(options){
    var settings = $.extend({
      'boxClass': 'box-header with-border',
      'addImageButton': 'btn btn-primary btn-sm',
    }, options);

    render(this, settings);
  }
}(jQuery));
```

1) Let's imagine our render() method is implemented using 25 different functions and they are 400 total lines of code long. Some of these functions are responsible for drawing the UI, some of them doing ajax queries, some of them is just some helpful snippets I made to reduce the amounts (and the ugly-ness) of the code.

How I could split this code into separate files? As far as I understand, I need to write code in different files, then use a tool like grunt/gulp to create a task or watcher to merge them all into a single *.js file (and probably provide a minified version as well), but right now I'm a bit confused about how I should do that. Is there any kind of 'best practice' thing, or any common approach to such thing to make sure that my code will be less confusing for the other possible maintainers?

2) Let's say that default settings is an array of 70 [probably nested] elements, and I want to access one of them in onButtonPress function. Oh, also different one I want to access in someOther function, and there's a few I need for deleteForm() function, so generally it would be better for my code if settings array will be something I could access from pretty much every place of the code, and most important thing, I could have 5-6 instances of my form on the page, so I cannot use a local-scope variable in plugin file for that.

I read about the approach of saving settings in the data fields, but it feels a bit weird for me to be frank. Is there's any better way I could implement it?

3) Let's say that my plugin is growing, and now I want to add a few more pre-defined settings for Bootstrap and Sematic UI frameworks adding to AdminLTE I use now.

Of course, generally I want my $('#form').myAwesomeForm({}) call to not be 70-lines long, so generally I'm looking for a way to somehow move the default settings in another file, to say "myplugin-defaults-lte.js", so then I could do something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="myplugin-defaults-bootstrap.min.js">
<script type='text/javascript' src="myplugin.min.js">
<script type='text/javascript'>
   // Here's my form. Already bootstrap-customized.
   $('#form').myAwesomeForm();
</script>
```

I'm not sure if it's the best pattern, but perhaps you got the idea. So generally, can anyone please provide a simple code snippet, or something like this, because at this point things starting to be confusing as hell to me, so I'm really not sure how to approach it correct way?